# Regex - How to count word in sql text?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I want to count **"CREATE"** word in sql text but I don't want to count with comment.

This is my work **PHP** regex pattern. But it don't work on **JavaScript** or **C#.** How can I convert **Javascript** or **C#** Regex pattern ? I want to get match count on **Javascript** or **C#**

https://regex101.com/r/oB7pA2/7#pcre

This Regex pattern is not working on **C#**

```
var asd = Regex.Matches("CREATE TABLE TEST (COLUMNA NUMBER);", "(\\/\\*(?:(?!\\/\\*).|(?1))*?\\*\\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|^\\s*CREATE").Count;
```

[image]

Best Regards

Comment: So, you try to avoid matching inside *nested* comments? Your right screen shows an unclosed comment  - do you also need to support that case?

Comment: @stribizhev , Yes like this https://regex101.com/r/oB7pA2/7#pcre but this is php regex pattern. I want to regex with Javascript

Comment: Wow, forget about a regex solution then. JS does not support recursion with regex. A parser should be written (or found it there is one already for this task).

Comment: @stribizhev , Can I make this with C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to split the process into three steps

### 1. Remove the comments

I've only quickly tested this but it does seem to work with my nested comments test cases. **You are going to want to write test cases and and prove this regex works for your cases.**

Note that this doesn't "require" the closing of comments `*/` because that could cause "catastrophic backtracking". If it is important to you to error when an unclosed comment is in the string you should write a separate RegEx for that.

#### Regular Expression

```
(?:/\*(?:[^*/]+|\*[^/]|/[^*]|/\*(?:[^*/]+|\*[^/]|/[^*])*(?:\*/)?)*(?:\*/)?|-- [^\r\n]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/sO5vR1/2

#### Visualisation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Code

```
var modified = original.replace(/(?:\/\*(?:[^*\/]+|\*[^\/]|\/[^*]|\/\*(?:[^*\/]+|\*[^\/]|\/[^*])*(?:\*\/)?)*(?:\*\/)?|-- [^\r\n]+)/ig, "");
```

### 2. Remove quoted strings

We don't want to count `CREATE` if it's in a quoted string

NOTE: You might also want to handle brackets (`[` `]`) if you believe they might to contain the word `CREATE`.

#### Regular Expression

```
'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

https://regex101.com/r/rZ9nV7/1

#### Visualisation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Code

```
modified = modified.replace(/'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/ig, "");
```

### 3. Count occurrences of "CREATE"

#### Code

```
var count = (modified.match(/\bCREATE\b/ig) || []).length;
```